# Send Emails from localhost when resetting password and more (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5

I wanted to test some of the functionality of my web application. 
I basically want to see the emails being sent to the users on registration and when they forget their password.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 default Identity, and I want to see what kind of emails the users get, so I went to the application and clicked on forgot password and I input my email, but I never received any email. I guess this is because I am working on localhost, is there anyway I can test this and other email functionality, without making massive changes in default code by ASP.NET?

Hope someone can help me, I am very new to ASP.NET MVC

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need a SMTP server to send email from and you can specify details in code or web.config.

in code it will be something like

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("ServerName");
```

//then authentication process if any

//then create message

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg.From="email@email.com";
mailMsg.To.Add("ifany@to.com");
mailMsg.Subject="YourSubject";
mailMsg.body="What Up!";
```

//send it

```
smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fake SMTP server like [fakeSMTP](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/). It's dead simple to use and  listens on whatever port you configure it with, by default this will be `127.0.0.1:25`

[image: FakeSMTP]

Having downloaded that, then set up the standard SMTP settings either in code or via webconfig:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <!-- Method#1: Configure smtp server credentials -->
        <smtp from="youremail@gmail.com">
            <network enableSsl="false" host="localhost" port="25" />
        </smtp>

        <!-- Method#2: Dump emails to a local directory -->
        <!--
        <smtp from="some-email@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <network host="localhost" />
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\temp\"/>
        </smtp>
        -->
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

And then you configure Identity to send by overriding the Email service in `ApplicationUserManager`:

```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
          this.EmailService = new TestEmailService();
        }
    }
```

Where `TestEmailService` is a class that implements `IIdentityMessageService`:

```
public class TestEmailService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
        var myMessage = new MailMessage();
        // this defines email and name of the sender
        //myMessage.From = new MailAddress("no-reply@tech.trailmax.info", "My Awesome Admin");

        // set where we are sending the email
        myMessage.To.Add(message.Destination);
        myMessage.Subject = message.Subject;
        myMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // make sure all your messages are formatted as HTML
        myMessage.Body = message.Body;


        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await client.SendMailAsync(myMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

If you were smart you'd actually inject the service into `ApplicationUserManager`  instead so:

```
  public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IIdentityMessageService emailService)
            : base(store)
        {
          this.EmailService = emailService;
        }
    }
```

And then either use your DI container to inject this in production or just mock in the test service when testing:

```
var appMan = new ApplicationUserManager(userStoreInstance, new TestEmailService());
```

Then do some registration etc in your app and then switch to `fakeSMTP`, click on an email and it will open in your default email client. You can also save mails sent to disk which can be handy for additional debug.